# 入れ子構造for文のイテレーション

Tags: python3

```
num_list = [[0 * 100]] * 2 
for i in range(4): 
    for j in range(100): 
        num_list[i].append(j)

print(num_list)
```

として

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100], [0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100]]
```

のような配列を作りたいのですが、結果として

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100, 0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100],[0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100, 0, 1, 2, 3 -- 100]]
```

となってしまいます。

明らかにイテレーションの理解不足だと思うのですが、 
どなたかご助言していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: `num_list = [list(range(101))] * 2` ではいかがでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

分かりやすく書くとこんな感じじゃないでしょうか。

```
# python3 --
num_list = []
for _ in range(2):
    nums = []
    for num in range(101):
        nums.append(num)
    num_list.append(nums)
print(num_list)
```

短く書きたいのであれば、下記のようにすれば良いです。

```
# python3 --
num_list = [list(range(101))] * 2
print(num_list)
```

UPDATE

ラッシーさんから指摘があったので追記します。

上記の書き方だと、num_list にある ２つのリストは同じオブジェクトが参照されてしまうので、
あまり良い書き方ではありませんでした。以下のようなことが起きてしまいます。

```
 # python3 --
 num_list = [list(range(101))] * 2
 num_list[0][0] = 999
 # 1番目のリストの最初の要素を書き換えると、同じオブジェクトを参照してるので
 # 2番目のリストの最初の要素の値も書き換わってしまう
 print(num_list[1][0]) # => 999
```

あらためて、２つのリストを独立させた状態で生成する方法を記載します。

```
# python3 --
num_list = [list(range(101)) for _ in range(2)]
```

Comment: `[range(101)] * 2`ですと中身は配列ではなくrangeのままですし、かといって、`[list(range(101)] * 2`では二つが同じオブジェクトになるので、やりたいことと違う物になるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: あぁそうですね。rangeはpython3だとそうなっちゃいますね。２つが同じオブジェクトになるのもよろしくないですね。ありがとうございます。回答を修正します。

Comment: なるほど配列の宣言に問題があったのですか。ありがとうございました！